# Closing iAd Banner changes the view controller frame

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iad

I have a problem while showing an iAd banner. The small banner is placed at the bottom of the view, and when I click on it, it's shown in full screen, that's the normal behavior, but when I close it, it returns to its previous size, but the view controller appears moved, it appears with y = 0, so it appears under the status bar, but before opening the ad, it was placed below the status bar, I've tried to reset the banner's frame in the delegate method  (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner but without success.

Anyone has faced this problem before?

Thank you very much!

Comment: of course it will, because as you close your iAd your controller invokes `- (void)viewWillAppear()` method, you can check it.

Comment: yes it invokes viewWillAppear but I don't do anything in this method that can move the views up. I've debugged and the frame of the window and the view are in x=0 and y=0..

Comment: @diegomen Did you ever figure the issue out? I'm having the same exact problem!

Comment: I can't remember very well, and I don't have the code of that project, but I think it was something with the main window, the banner resized it, but i can't remember.. sorry about that

Comment: As @diegomen pointed out, try to print out the window frame and view frame values in ViewWillAppear method and compare them to see if the window size is altered, if yes, then you can change it yourself to what it was before.